# FragmentPagerAdapter GetItem is never called?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-tabs

I'm trying to initate a simple tab swipe, But when I'm adding the PagerAdapter the getItem method is never called..
I cant find the reason for this.

Activity:

```
public class ProfileActivity extends Activity implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_acivity);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.profile_view_pager);
    ProfilePagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ProfilePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    ActionBar.Tab friendsTab = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab postsTab   = actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tribesTab  = actionBar.newTab();

    tribesTab.setText("TRIBES");
    postsTab.setText("POSTS");
    friendsTab.setText("FRIENDS");

    tribesTab.setTabListener(this);
    postsTab.setTabListener(this);
    friendsTab.setTabListener(this);


    actionBar.addTab(friendsTab);
    actionBar.addTab(postsTab);
    actionBar.addTab(tribesTab);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_profile_acivity, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
{

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
{

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
{

}
}
```

(I also tried with FragmentActivity Though I do not need the V4 and I'm using the V13)

My adapter:

```
private class ProfilePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{

    Fragment fragment = new ProfileTribeFragment();

    public ProfilePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i)
    {
        Log.i("D","NO :{");
        if(i==0)
        {
            fragment = new ProfileFriendsFragment();
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            fragment = new ProfilePostsFragment();
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            fragment = new ProfileTribeFragment();
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And all the 3 Fragments look like that:

```
public class ProfileTribeFragment extends Fragment {


public ProfileTribeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_tribe, container, false);
}
```

}

I Just cant figure what I'm doing wrong.
The Log.i on the getItem is never seen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you return Zero on your `getCount()` so there will be no Item inside your PagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Page adapter will bind no page as defined page count inside **getCount()** but in your case you have return static **'0' zero** count so pager adapter will not bind any page over there and you not able to seen any page data there. You need to set no page count inside **getCount()** method like 3 as below example :

```
@Override
public int getCount(){
  return 3; // 3 is no of page count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me nothing worked Then I found the solution -  Instead of FragmentPagerAdapter, use FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Return the number of fragments in `getCount()` method:

```
int fragmentCount=3;

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return fragmentCount;
}
```